# Casting a sub-type to a type defined as generic

Tags: java, generics

I have an Interface `Int1`. I a have a class `Cls1` implementing `Int1`. And a generic class `Cls2<Cls1>`.

Now I'm writing a method:

```
private void <T extends Int1> test(Cls2<Cls1> arg1) {
    ...
    //I try to cast a Cls2<Cls1> into a Cls2<Int1>: it works
    Cls2<Int1> test1 = (Cls2<Int1>) arg1;
    //I try to cast a Cls2<Cls1> into a Cls2<T>: doesn't work
    Cls2<T> test2 = (Cls2<T>) arg1; //compilation error
}
```

Considering that `T` extends `Int1`, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: "it works" because it's redundant: you don't need to cast a type to itself.

Comment: "compilation error" because `T` is not always `Cls1`; it *might* be `Cls1`, but it could also be a subclass of it.

Comment: What is the point of making the method generic (adding `<T extends Int1>`) when `T` is not used in the method signature.

Comment: I think you got it backwards. The first line should be a compile error, and the second line should compile fine (with a warning).

Answer (score 0):

The code below compiles w/o errors in intellij.

```
interface Int1{}
class Cls2<T>{}
class Cls1 implements Int1 {}


private <T extends Int1> void test(Cls2<Cls1> arg1) {
    Cls2<Int1> test1 = (Cls2<Int1>)(Cls2<?>)arg1;
    Cls2<T> test2 = (Cls2<T>) arg1;
}
```

In java, class parameterized by subclass and super class are not related. You need to cast to a `<?>` first.

Overall, if what I have above reflects your code correctly, it's a very strange use of generics. Please make sure your design is correct.

Comment: I didn't show my complete use case, but it's because the returned value of the method is typed by `T`, as well as one of the argument. And somewhere in this method, I obtain an object typed with a subtype of `T`. I couldn't understand why it was invalid to return it... Is there any way to do this without warnings and without suppressing the warning?